# Problem with locating button on map (on same activity) in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm writing an application in Android where background is a map and I want to put on this background some buttons like "Search", "Login".
I have created xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogReg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="@string/log_amp_reg"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" >

    </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        tilesource="Mapnik"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and also Java code like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MapView map = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(12.5);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(49.20, 19.94);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

        Button logreg = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogReg);
        logreg.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        map.onResume();
    }
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        map.onPause();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginRegister.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

So my question is: 
Why I can't see the button on android screen, I see only moveable map?
Anybody could help me with this issue?

Comment: Why are there two maps? Also, have you tried giving a background color to the layout containing the buttons.

Comment: I didn't check the second, I was thinking I deleted it. Yes, I have tried this option with background color but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use fill_parent or match_parent as height for your map, if you do so, it will occupy the entire screen height. Since you are using LinearLayout you can use weightSum and add layout_weights to your button and map

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem maps in the map sizes. You can edit them.......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogReg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="@string/log_amp_reg" />

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" >
    </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>

  
</LinearLayout>
```